# Azure Pipeline cmdLine error Bash exited with code '1'

Tags: android, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

[image: error image description here]

I am going through the azure pipeline for my Android project. Issue is that local.properties file is in .gitignore so getting error local.properties not found for this i added its in secure file and now in YAML file i am downloading and installing taht secure file.
But I am stuck on the CmdLine step. line 18 error ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.,

As for the pipeline yaml, I am using this template for android

```
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android

trigger:
- dev_pooja


pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: localProperties
  displayName: 'Download Local Properties file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'local.properties'

- script: |
    echo Installing $(localProperties.secureFilePath) to the trusted directory...
    sudo chown root:root $(localProperties.secureFilePath)
    sudo chmod a+r $(localProperties.secureFilePath)
    sudo ln -s -f /etc/ssl/certs/ $(localproperties.secureFilePath)

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDebug'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: "**/*.apk"
    targetFolder: "$(build.artifactsStagingDirectory)"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: Few quick pointers: 1.  You are using a _macos_latest_ agent. But there's no `-t` flag in [**ln** command in the OSX](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ln/). 2. `JavaToolInstaller@0` step should be executed before the `Gradle@2` step because the latter is using attributes such as `jdkVersionOption` and `jdkArchitectureOption`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error line : `sudo ln -s -t /etc/ssl/certs/ $(localproperties.secureFilePath)`.

Try removing `-t` flag. In addition,  you may need `-f` flag:  If the target file already exists, then unlink it so that the link may occur.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply  but its not working for me, getting error that local.properties not found

Comment: Could you please provide the latest error message and the line of code where it occurs by editing the question?

Comment: Edited the YAMl file in question, now the error is: 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > The file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/local.properties' could not be found

Comment: its the same error that occured before

Answer (score 0):

try to install the latest version of pwsh on your agent.